# Error in Function execution

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
USE [Curatas_Live]
GO
/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[BreakStringIntoRows]    Script Date: 22-02-2017 12:52:32 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[BreakStringIntoRows] (@CommadelimitedString   varchar(1000))
RETURNS  [@Result   VARCHAR(100)]
AS
BEGIN
         declare @result VARCHAR(100)
           DECLARE @IntLocation INT
    DECLARE @ResultCode VARCHAR(100)
    SET @Result = ''
        WHILE (CHARINDEX(',',    @CommadelimitedString, 0) > 0)
        BEGIN
              SET @IntLocation =   CHARINDEX(',',    @CommadelimitedString, 0)      



          SELECT @ResultCode = RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@CommadelimitedString,   0, @IntLocation))) 
     SELECT @Result =@Result + ITMSGRPNAME FROM OITB
     WHERE ITMSGRPCODE=@ResultCode

          SET @CommadelimitedString = STUFF(@CommadelimitedString,   1, @IntLocation,   '') 
    END

    SELECT @ResultCode = RTRIM(LTRIM(@CommadelimitedString))--LTRIM and RTRIM to ensure blank spaces are removed
SELECT @Result =@Result + ITMSGRPNAME FROM OITB
     WHERE ITMSGRPCODE=@ResultCode
    RETURN @Result
END
```

Comment: Please explain what is going wrong

Comment: Do you really expect an answer? Just *Error in Function execution* and some code? Please read [How to ask a good SQL question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056)  and [How to create a MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and state your actual error message!

Comment: I got following error     Msg 2715, Level 16, State 3, Procedure BreakStringIntoRows, Line 26
Column, parameter, or variable #0: Cannot find data type @Result   VARCHAR(100).
Parameter or variable '' has an invalid data type.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax should be as presented below, object name is not required :

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[BreakStringIntoRows] (@CommadelimitedString   varchar(1000))
RETURNS VARCHAR(100) 
AS ....
```